# What is the linux operation behind the start of an activity? (Android)

Tags: android, linux

I was asked this question by an employer recently and could not answer. I have seen linux like commands using Android Studio when running an application and researching topics but have not ever needed to use them, therefore I am not knowledgable on the topic. Where can I find the information on the **direct connection** between Android and Linux?

Comment: Buy a book, like [Karim Yaghmour's _Embedded Android_](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021094.do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From *Embedded Android -Karim Yaghmour*

When the user clicks an icon to start an app from his home screen, the first
thing that happens is the `Launcher’s onClick() callback is called`

To deal with the event, the Launcher will then call, through
Binder, the `startActivity() method of the Activity Manager service`.

The service will
then call the `startViaZygote()` method, which will `open a socket to the Zygote` and
ask it to start the Activity

Comment: If the question is only about activities I don´t think there´s nothing to do with zygote, fork or any other SO stuff because you´re already with the VM running, the application loaded and a new window handler is created by the UI thread and give the control and render capability to the implementing classes

Comment: @eduyayo - untrue.  When start is fired, there may or may not already be a process in existence to host that Activity.

Comment: "when starting an activity" there MUST be an application instance... And, before that, the vm must be running, the cygote instanced...

Comment: @eduyayo - that is a bit of a confused statement of things.  If a suitable process with a VM or equivalent functionality belonging to the Activity's package does not already exist to start the Activity in, then zygote will as needed fork creating a new process with a new instance of the VM functionality to provide it.  Each package's VM functionality is thus independent, and may or may not be present when not needed.  But due to shared heritage through zygote all of these instances can share the code pages of system libraries, yielding an efficient memory footprint.

Answer (score -2):

What is happening at the lowest Linux level is a **fork**(2) and **execve**(2).  The Android operating system is Linux.

Comment: No.  What makes Android quite unique and efficient is that **no variety of  exec() is utilized**.  Instead, zygote forks and specializes by loading additional code of the app, *without* a new exec().  This lets it retain all the pre-loaded shared mappings of system libraries (requiring only copy-on-write of data pages), which calling an exec() function would wipe out.  However, this is only required if there is not already a suitable process belonging to the Activity's package which can host it - if there already is one, then no new process needs to be forked.